# Disable Facebook facial recognition

Tags: facebook, photos, facial-recognition

I recently noticed that Facebook was tagging me in my wife's photos that she did not tag me in. Apparently Facebook now tags people automagically by facial recognition.

How can I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to Account > Privacy Settings
   [image]
2. Choose "Custom" and then "Customise Settings"
   [image]
3. Under "Things Others Share", next to "Suggest photos of me to friends", click "Edit Settings"
   [image]
4. Next to "Suggest photos of me to friends", choose "Disabled"
   [image]